# php-fpm log filling with configuration test successful

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have nginx and php-fpm running and I just noticed my /var/log/php5-fpm.log is filling with this message once a second or so:

```
NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful
```

Any idea why? Is this a problem?

Comment: I think I was seeing this so often because I had upstart and init competing to start php. Upstart is working on its own now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just disable PHP Notice in php.ini / fpm conf

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

It won't cause any issues.

Comment: Would I miss any important error messages if I did that?

Comment: No. They are just Run time notices. Usually they will be turned off in live servers. But E_ERROR, E_WARNING, E_PARSE are important.